# How to access array from a different target (KeyboardViewController)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just beginning Swift after spending a considerable amount of time learning java. I'm trying to create a keyboard app. I created a new target KeyBoardViewController, and am trying to access an array I created and mutated within my ViewController class. I am a bit confused reading the documentation regarding access levels in swift. I see that my ViewController.swift and KeyboardViewController.swift are in different folders. I imported my module containing ViewController into my KeyboardViewController, but it still is unable to access the array I need.

I've read into using a struct(), . notation, and declaring the ViewController class as public, but none of these recognized my array. When I used a struct(), it seemed to reset my array each time I referenced it in ViewController and still did not recognize anything in KeyboardViewController. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

In either of your classes, you can do something like this:

```
import UIKit
var arr = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Then you can access `arr` in either of your classes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately when I try this it still does not find the symbol. Could this be because it is from a differnet module?

Answer (score 0):

Create another class with a static instance of variable viewController as follows:

`class DataStore {
 static var yourArray:[String]?
 }`

then store the instance of array in ViewController class as follows:

`DataStore.yourArray = self.array`

later in class KeyboardViewController you can access the array instance as follows:

`DataStore.yourArray`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Trying this method, I get another odd issue. Everything compiles, but I get a crash. I tried printing the size of my array while I'm mutating it in ViewController (by using DataStore.yourArray.append) and the size will say 5, however when I then go to my KeyboardViewController the size is back to 0 and I crash since I am unable to index into it. What could be causing the array to be different between files? I had to modify your code a little bit because I was getting an error:Thanks

Comment: Here is what I changed it to:      import UIKit
class Main {
    var pics :[UIImage]
    init(pics : [UIImage]) {
        self.pics = [UIImage]()
    }
}
var instance = Main(pics: [UIImage]())

Comment: As you are storing array of UIImages, you just need to import UIKit in class DataStore & it should be working